# I'm not able to perform validation for the input data in my mongoengine model class

Tags: python, django, regex, validation, mongoengine

```
class TextBoxValues(DynamicDocument):
    entity_id = StringField(max_length=200, required=True) 
    textbox_type = StringField(max_length=1000, required=True)  
    regexp = re.compile('[A-Za-z]')
    entity_value = StringField(regex=regexp,max_length=None, required=True)
```

I was using the regex parameter to perform validation which is not working for me,it still takes input in any format, why?

Comment: Maybe it expects a string? Or an anchored pattern? Try `regexp = r'^[A-Za-z]+$'`

Comment: Didn't work, still takes input in any format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex to provide to `StringField(regex=)` should in fact be a string but it also work if you give it a compiled regex.

The problem is your regex actually. It should be `regexp=r'^[A-Za-z]+$'` as @wiktor-stribiżew suggested in the comment.

The minimal example below demonstrates that the regex works as expected

```py
from mongoengine import *
connect()    # connect to 'test' database

class TextBoxValues(Document):
    entity_value = StringField(regex=r'^[A-Za-z]+$')

TextBoxValues(entity_value="AZaz").save() # passes validation

TextBoxValues(entity_value="AZaz1").save() # raises ValidationError (String value did not match validation regex: ['entity_value'])
```

Comment: So basically what i was trying to do is, I was talking data through this model class and serializing it and giving this serialized input to another model class which i have to save as a document.

Comment: What i've figured is this validation only works if i save the same model class and just taking data from that model class won't validate the data